# jqGrid - odd behavior by both Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that is populated in one of two ways - a submit button will create a row on a table which is then loaded on a refresh of the jqGrid, and also by selecting a row on the grid, which will cause a submit & cancel button to appear, allowing the user to re-submit a previously submitted item.

The desired behavior (on the jqGrid) is (1) for messages to be shown on a refresh of the jqGrid as items are submitted to the table and (2) for selected messages in the jqGrid to be re-submitted when the user selects & re-submits them.  The re-submit/cancel buttons are not to be visible unless a row is selected, at which point controls elsewhere on the page are locked and not selectable until the user submits or cancels the selection.  When re-submitted, the item is added again, and the grid is refreshed, and any selections are cleared & the re-submit/cancel buttons are hidden.  On a Cancel, it does not do a refresh of the grid, but clears the selection made, and hides the re-submit/cancel buttons.

In Firefox, when one of the previously submitted items is selected (for example 4 rows are present & row 2 is clicked on), row #1 is highlighted & if submitted, it's row 1 (and not row 2) that is re-submitted.  It doesn't seem to matter which order the rows are selected, but rows 1 & 3 are the only ones who are highlighted as selected when they are clicked on.

In IE, a couple things are an issue.  First, no footer row displays.  Second, clicking on any row doesn't show the buttons or appear to select the row in any way.

Below is the code for the jqGrid.

```
    $("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        url: changedUrl,
        datatype: "xml",
        colNames: ["Destination", "Message Text", "Send Time"],
               colModel:[
            {name:"Destination",index:"Destination",width:col1width,align:"left", xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>Destination",sortable:false},
            {name:"MessageText",index:"MessageText",width:col2width,align:"left",xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>MessageText",sortable:false},
            {name:"SendTime",index:"SendTime",width:col3width,align:"left",xmlmap:"Rowset>Row>SendTime",sortable:false}
            ],
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: capMsg,
//      rowNum: nbrRows,
        rownum: 0,
        autowidth: false,
        //height: gridheight,
        height: "100%",
        width: gridwidth,
        //rowList:[10,20,30],
        toolbar: [true, "top"],
        pager: jQuery("#pager1"),
        sortname: "SendTime",
        defaults: {
            recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
            emptyrecords:  "No records to view",
            pgtext: "Page  {0} of {1}"
            },

        // code to view the row follows
        onSelectRow:  function(id) {
        //  $(this).jqGrid("viewGridRow", id, {closeOnEscape:true});
            var gridRow = $(this).jqGrid("getRowData",id);
            $(".sendAgainControls").show();
            $("#dList").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#cmlist").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#SendMsg").prop("disabled", true);

            $("#ReSend").click(function() {
                //console.log("ReSend Button was pressed.  Dest = " + gridRow.Destination + "  CM = " + gridRow.MessageText);
                ReSendMessage(gridRow.Destination, gridRow.MessageText);
                $(".sendAgainControls").hide();
                $("#dList").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#cmlist").prop("disabled", false);
                //$(this).jqGrid("resetSelection");

                });

            $("#Cancel").click(function() {
                $(".sendAgainControls").hide();
                $("#dList").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#cmlist").prop("disabled", false);
                $("#myGrid").jqGrid("setSelection", "-1");
                ReloadGrid();
                });
            },

        xmlReader:  { 
            root: "Rowsets", 
                    row: "Row",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "Destination"
            }
        });
```

Since I've got multiple issues in each browser, I'm not sure where to start on it.

The HTML for the grid follows:

```
<table id="myGrid" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width: 80%">
<div id="pager1"></div>
</table>
<table id="ReSend" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  style="width: 80%">
<tr>
<td class="sendAgainControls"  align="center">
<div id="sendAgain">
<input id="ReSend" type="submit" value="Re-Send Selected"  />
<input id="Cancel" type="submit" value="Cancel Re-Send"  />
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'd appreciate any thoughts on what's happening with each browser.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0):

This must have been a memory issue.  Performing as described above 3 days ago, but when the system was re-started, all the issues went away.